# How to Properly use Array of Structures of C

Tags: arrays, c, data-structures, struct, structure

I'm recently started learning about structures in C Language. I tried out a sample program to extend my learning curve. But, here in this subject, I'm facing few errors. Shall anyone please figure out the errors in the following program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main() {
 int i;
 struct elements {
  int z; /* Atomic Number */
  float m; /* Mass Number */
  char *name;
  char *symbol;
 };
 struct elements e[5];
 e[0] = (struct elements){1,1.008,"Hydrogen","H"};
 e[1] = (struct elements){2,4.0026,"Helium","He"};
 e[2] = (struct elements){3,6.94,"Lithium","Li"};
 clrscr();
 for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
  printf("Element Name: %s\n",e[i].name);
  printf("Symbol: %s\n",e[i].symbol);
  printf("Atomic Number: %d\n",e[i].z);
  printf("Atomic Mass: %0.2f\n",e[i].m);
 }
 getch();
 return 0;
}
```

This shows the following Error messages:

[image]

Comment: You seem to be using TurboC which was ancient already when the C99 standard came, and added the features you are using. You just can't use [compound literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) in that old environment. There are a few very good modern C and C++ environments with modern compilers which can handle your code, even free ones. Please upgrade to something modern.

Comment: I really doubt Turbo C supports assignments using compound literals.

Comment: **Don't use TurboC**. This antiquated tool is older than you. If your teacher told you to use turbo c, he should be fired or the school should be closed alltogether

Comment: While I think the best suggestion would be to dump Turbo C and get some decent compiler, you could use standard array initializators instead of assignments: `struct elemens e[5] = {{1,1.008."Hydrogen","H"}, {2,4.0026,"Helium","He"}, ... };`.

Comment: Thanks Stack Overflow Community. My code works fine on online compilers. Even though we are in modern world, many educational institutions badly focus only on TurboC. That's the fact that I am using it. I will upgrade myself soon.

Comment: Unless you are using [this computer from 1989](https://sprignaturemoves.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/tandy-5000-mc-1989-ad.jpg), you probably shouldn't be using a compiler from 1989 either. (And yes, that's only $8499 for this beauty, with the money value of year 1989!)

Comment: @lundin Shall you suggest me a better modern c compiler?

Comment: @BathriVijay gcc? Depending on OS you might already have it. For Windows you'll have to download gcc/mingw64 together with your favourite flavour of IDE.

Comment: @BathriVijay for Windows there is the Micsosoft's Visual Studio Community Edition which is also free and comes with a very nice and easy to use debugger. But the compiler that comes with is is admittedly not as good as gcc, but more than good enough for beginners

Comment: @Jabberwocky MSVC is kind of just as old as Turbo C though. I actually think Turbo C has better C89 compliance than MSVC 2019-something...

Comment: @Lundin the OP's code compiles with my Visual Studio 2022. AFAIK the only thing that modern Microsoft C compilers do not support is VLAs.

Comment: @Jabberwocky https://godbolt.org/z/zbGbMcvff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the other comments, if this is what you have to work with, then you'll still be wanting a solution.

Try:

```
struct elements e[5] = {
    {1,1.008,"Hydrogen","H"},
    {2,4.0026,"Helium","He"},
    {3,6.94,"Lithium","Li"}
 };
```

What you had would work on later compilers (although some will want `char const *` in the struct for `name` and `symbol` to accept string literals), but its actually not very pretty to read, nor is it necessary when you are defining the entire array.

If you do it this way, you can omit the array size (change `[5]` to `[]`) and it will size according to the number of elements provided.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using a standard C compiler so you can't write the code in the standard C language.

You'll have to resort to the 1989 version of the C language known as "C89"/"C90". It doesn't support the *compound literal* feature `(struct elements){1,1.008,"Hydrogen","H"};`, because that one was added to the C language 23 years ago.